# How do I convert this cURL request to UrlFetchApp?

Tags: javascript, json, curl, google-apps-script, urlfetch

So the website gave us some code samples. I've managed to do GET functions well enough, but I can't seem to post anything. Here is the sample below

```
curl -X POST https://api.teachworks.com/v1/customers/family \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Token token={access_token}' \
  -d '{
        "customer": 
          {         
            "first_name": "Jake & Paula",       
            "last_name": "Jackson",
            "email": "jakej@example.com",
            "home_phone": "123-123-1234",
            "mobile_phone": "123-123-1234",
            "status": "Active"
           }
       }'
```

Here is my code

```
function test(){
  url = "https://api.teachworks.com/v1/customers/family";
  var token = {api_key};
  headers = {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Token token="+token
    };
  payload = '{ "customer": \
{"first_name": "Jake & Paula", \
"last_name": "Jackson", \
"email": "jakej@example.com",\
"home_phone": "123-123-1234", \
"mobile_phone": "123-123-1234", \
"status": "Active" }}';
  Logger.log(payload);
  options = {
    "headers" : headers,
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
  }
  Logger.log(options);
  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Every time I run it I get the same error:

Request failed for https://api.teachworks.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: Required parameter missing: customer

If I understand correctly, the payload is equivalent to -d. so my code should be right. Please let me know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: what are those backslashes doing? I have never used them in urlfetchapp

Comment: You might just want to make the plain pojo, and then use `JSON.stringify` on the plain object, rather than try to write the JSON string directly. Also, try just using the pojo, too.

Comment: Backslashes in javascript let you do line breaks.

Comment: You didn't set `contentType` in options

Comment: @TheMaster it's not enough that I listed "accept : application/json" in the header?

Comment: @Tanaike The curl command actually didn't work. It's from the website documentation as an example but it didn't work. The python example worked just fine though.

Answer (score 1):

@theMaster was right about it missing the ContentType.

Accept in the headers is the receivable mimeType at the client side. contentType is for the option of UrlFetchApp and the same with Content-Type of the headers. Content-Type is the mimeType of request body. In your case, contentType of application/json is required to be used. Ref By the way, can I ask you whether you could confirm that your curl command worked fine? source comments @Tanaike

```
function test(){
  url = "https://api.teachworks.com/v1/customers/family";
  var token = {api_key};
  headers = {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Token token="+token
    };
  payload = '{ "customer": \
{"first_name": "Jake & Paula", \
"last_name": "Jackson", \
"email": "jakej@example.com",\
"home_phone": "123-123-1234", \
"mobile_phone": "123-123-1234", \
"status": "Active" }}';
  Logger.log(payload);
  options = {
    "headers" : headers,
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload,
    "contentType": "application/json"
  }
  Logger.log(options);
  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the credit, but please include the actual answer. Code-only answers have less value for future readers. Explain what's changed and why. You could just write Tanake's comment in your own words. See [answer]