# Invalid format for field - vehicle registration number when using Vehicle Enquiry Service API (gov.uk)

Tags: google-apps-script, post, urlfetch

I am trying to use Google Apps Script with the Vehicle Enquiry Service API to pull vehicle data. The end goal will be to have a vehicle list which can check vehicle status' on regular intervals.

I have used the API documentation and some trial and error and have only achieved a 400 error ("status":"400","code":"ENQ108","detail":"Invalid format for field - vehicle registration number","title":"Bad Request").

```
function myFunction() {

    //var url = "https://uat.driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicle-enquiry/v1/vehicles" // test URL 
    var url = "https://driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicle-enquiry/v1/vehicles"// actual URL 
    var key = "My API Key"// not called below 
    var data = { "registrationNumber": "AA19AAA " };
  
  var header = {

    "x-api-key" : 'My API Key', // Key hidden due to having to apply for it and having useage limits
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }

  var options = {
  method: 'POST',

  'headers': header,       
  'x-api-key': key,
  data
};
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)
  Logger.log(response);
}

function fetchExample() {
 let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://example.com");
 Logger.log(response);
}
```

I have tried a wide variety of combinations & orders of the data I need to submit as well as various other posts methods regarding API's and the code examples from the 'code examples' on the API documentation although I believe my issue is that I am using Apps Script which is not used in the code examples.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. "I have tried..." without showing what actually have tried doesn't help anyone, by the other hande we already have a lot of questions about using Google Apps Script to make POST requests  / use APIs. Please spend some time searching this site for helpful answers. If you need further help, add a brief but meaningful description of your search efforts (include links of the most relevant posts, and tell us what was difficult to understand / apply to your case) as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Tip: Take the cUrl examples as the starting point and search for posts about "translating" cURL to Google Apps Script URL Fetch service like https://stackoverflow.com/q/62140937/1595451, https://stackoverflow.com/q/59689521/1595451,

Comment: In your question, in order to know the specification of the API you want to use, I would like to recommend including the official document of the API.